# How can i make caching server on different host in django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I have django app where my files are hosted on `Amazon s3` and site is on `Ec2`.

Now  my BW cost is high because of too much data gets downloaded from S3.

Now in Digital ocean i can get server for 10$ where BW `2TB` is avaiable.

I don't want to shift the server , so i am thinking of some setup which i am not sure is valid or not.

I want that when user clicks on download file then that request should go to `some service` on `Digital ocean` or may be on same server which first checks if the file is availabe on DG server. If file is there then DG should serve the file for download and if its not there then file from `AWS S3` will be served and then copied to DG server so that next request will be from DG ocean server. so i am planning to use 20GB space or more there to keep most frequently used file there.

Is setup like that possible or there is some better way to accomplish what i want

My webiste is `Django Python`

Comment: Why not? What's stopping you? I can't think of anything that would... `someserver.com/?file=http://amazonlink.com` - check if said link is stored locally, otherwise pull from amazon.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita thanks. actually i have not done anything like that. so first i was confirming whether its possible or not. can you point to me some ditrction on how should i approach it

Comment: You could set up nginx to look for files locally, then fall back to an app if it doesn't exist (this is a common nginx setup with try_files). The app then, could take a URL parameter from the path or get parameter, then pull the file from Amazon and place in the nginx path. The next hit would be served from Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your specific needs, but I think the most simple solution here is to just use a **reverse proxy** with **caching**.

This - off course - does only apply if you have your *main* files on amazon, and seeing your `DG` server as a non-persistent storage.

Nginx is really simple here and likely powerful enough. So what I would try in your situation:

(Assuming someone is accessing the file `http://satic.your-site.com/image/example.jpg`)

- 'static' request, handled by Nginx on `DG` server
- Nginx will check if the content is in its cache
- if yes, response is delivered directly from nginx cache
- if no, Nginx loads response from upstream server(s)

This has a lot of advantages and is really flexible. For example, if you do a lot of changes and want to invalidate the cache, just empty the corresponding directory (and maybe HUP the server).

#### Simple nginx config example:

```
proxy_cache_path  /var/lib/nginx/cache  levels=1:2   keys_zone=yoursite_cache:256m  max_size=5G;

upstream yoursite_upstream {
    server your-instance.s3.amazon.com:80 weight=1 fail_timeout=120s;
    # works as well with multiple backends. just for reference, as not needed with s3
    # server your-instance-2.s3.amazon.com:80 weight=1 fail_timeout=120s;
}


server {
    listen   *:80;
    server_name satic.your-site.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/satic.your-site.com.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/satic.your-site.com.error.log info;

    add_header X-Cache-Status;

    location / {
        proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        proxy_cache_valid  200 302  1440m;
        proxy_cache_valid  404  1m;
        proxy_cache yoursite_cache;

        proxy_pass http://yoursite_upstream;
    }
}
```

Comment: your-instance.s3.amazon.com should be your-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com (= amazonAWS.com, not amazon.com). yoursite_upstream should also be named the same, your-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com. Also, the add_header X-Cache-Status did not work ("invalid number of arguments in "add_header" directive")